# I'm trying to install electron JS but it crashes during installation

Tags: javascript, node.js, installation, electron, desktop

[image]

it just stop and nothing happen, i have tried to install different versions of node js, even with using git it happens the same thing
`[##################] | reify:lodash: timing reifyNode:node_modules/@types/node Completed in 859ms`

Comment: I don't see how git would be relevant here, are you able to install other packages? Can you install electron/other packages in other projects? Please give more information in your question

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can follow this official documentation https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start

Comment: I followed all the steps in the documentation but the same thing happens

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.